# Vba code for looking data between date

Tags: vba, date

I am quite new in VBA, I am trying to have a code looking for some price between some date.

I have the following date as below: and I am looking for the price

```
date    ______  Price a _______Price b

2015 03     
2015 04     
2015 05     
2015 06     
2015 07     
2015 08     
2015 10     
2015 11     
2015 12
```

on another tab:

```
period  ____startdate   ____endate  _____price a____   price b

month   ____  2015 03   ____2015 03 ____   10   ____      78

month   ____    2015 04 ____ 2015 04    ____    14  ____ 0

month    ____    2015 05    ____ 2015 05    ____    14  ____       12

month   ____     2015 06    ____ 2015 06    ____    89  ____ 0

month   ____     2015 07    ____ 2015 07    ____    12  ____ 0

month    ____     2015 08   ____ 2015 08     ____   85      ____    12

month   ____    2015 10 ____ 2015 10    ____    88  ____ 0

month    ____     2015 11   ____ 2015 11    ____    21    ____     17

month   ____     2015 12    ____ 2015 12    ____    85  ____ 0

quarter  ____     2015 01   ____ 2015 03    ____    48  ____       45

quarter     ____  2015 04   ____ 2015 06    ____    85  ____ 0

quarter   ____      2015 07 ____   2015 09 ____   85     ____       2

quarter  ____       2015 10 ____ 2015 12    ____     7   ____     17

year      ____      2015 01 ____ 2015 12    ____    17  ____       22
```

I am trying to get the price according the following rules depending on the start date and end date:

if the price B #  from 0 for the date  I am looking for
I will return the price B and A from the month and stop to looking

if the  Price B=0  for the month I will have a look on the quarter
if the price B # from 0  for the quarter I will secondly return the price B and A from the quarter and stop to looking

if it  Price B=0 for the quarter, I will have a look on the year
if the price B # from 0 for the year I will return the price B and A from the Year depending

if the price B for the date I am looking for is not empty I will thirdly return the price B and A from the year
I am struggling since one week and don't know how to figure out?

Maybe an idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: # From? Haven't come across that terminology....

Comment: it is not clear? sorry  maybe I should explain you on another way?

Comment: Not quite for me, but it's frobably just a use of # I don't know. Is it "differs from" (i.e. same as not equal to) or something else?

Comment: it exactly that, " differs from ", I don't know if you have an idea about this case?  thanks

Comment: Cool. Second, how are you planning to construct the quarterly price? Is it a case of average the months comprising the quarter, add them together, take the median... or something else?

Comment: in fact all the data are already calculated, for the month, quarter, and year

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is simpler than you think, though my guess is you haven't come across the `INDEX(<Array>, MATCH(<Target Value>, <Array with values>, 0))` pattern much before?

If you're able to change the labels on the lookup page so that each month, quarter, and year is actually unique, then this is enough - so add another column that does something like `IF(a1 = "Quarter", "Q" & choose(month(b1),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), If(a1 = "Month", "M" & Month(b1), "")) &"_Y" & year(b1)`

That gives you something to look up on your results take. Then you use several index/match formulae to look up first the month, then, if needed, the quarter, then the year entry. That formula would be based around:

`index(<price column you want>,Match("M" & Month(a1) &  "_Y" & Year(a1), <Helper column you just added>, 0))`

You can either then lookup up Price B for month, quarter, and year on 3 columns and then choose which lookup to perform again in a final results column for price a and b respectively, or you can nest these formulae to do it in one shot. The helper columns will be quicker if you have a lot of data, but it's up to you.

Comment: many thanks, I will try this solution, and let you know for the result

Comment: I am sorry I tried it but seems there is an issue of syntax or I do not underdand the formula:IF(a1 = "Quarter", "Q" & choose(month(b1),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), If(a1 = "Month", "M" & Month(b1), "")) &"_Y" & year(b1)

Comment: Did the index formula fail, or just the lookup one? The lookup one you'd need to adapt a fair bit; if the syntax is tricky you could try using VLOOKUP instead, which is a little easier to read. Either way, if the syntax is giving you trouble, you should definitely use as many helper columns as you need to be able to work out what's going on.

Comment: thanks,  I am trying manually for the vlookup and I will try with the index, I let you know for the  result

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you get a chance could you accept the answer? Thanks